# Doctrine mongo group query

Tags: mongodb, doctrine

I have problems to implement a groupBy with doctrine mongo db.

I followed this two guides:

http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/unique_items_map_reduce/

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/query-builder-api.html

Exactly, I want to make this groupBy: "select * from fonts where 1 group by family"

This is my code that don't works:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder();
$queryBuilder->group(array('family'), array('count' => 0));
$queryBuilder->reduce('function (obj, prev) { prev.count++; }');
$queryBuilder->sort($sort, $order);
return $queryBuilder;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might consider using the aggregation framework for simple grouping rather than doing M/R batch runs. See: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder();
$queryBuilder->group(array('family' => 1), array('count' => 0));
$queryBuilder->reduce('function (obj, prev) { prev.count += 1;}');
$queryBuilder->sort($sort, $order);
return $queryBuilder;
```

Answer (score 1):

The aggregation framework provides an easy way to process records and return computed results.

For example, our document is like this.

```
class Example
{
/**
  * @MongoDB\Field(type="int")
  */
 protected $noExample;

 /**
  * @MongoDB\Field(type="string")
  */
 protected $libelle;


 /**
  * @MongoDB\Field(type="string")
  */
 protected $family;

}
```

In ExampleRepository, we need to create this function.

```
public function groupByFamily()
{

$qb = $this->createAggregationBuilder('Document\Example');


    $qb->group()
       ->field('id')
       ->expression('$family')
       ->field('noExample')
       ->first('$noExample')
       ->field('libelle')
       ->first('$libelle')
       ->field('family')
       ->first('$family')
       ->field('number_record')
       ->sum(1);

    $results = $qb->execute();
    return $results;
}
```

You can [read more](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/1.2/reference/aggregation-builder.html#creating-an-aggregation-builder).